# Close form on deactivate breaks click event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a windows form in c# which should close when the user clicks anywhere outside of its bounds, eg:

```
form1.Deactivate += (o, e) => form1.Close();
```

My problem is, I would also like to catch the click event that caused the form to deactivate, but using the above code my mouse event handlers on the other forms in my application are never called.

For example, I have a click handler on a second visible form in my application:

```
form2.MouseClick += OnForm2Click
```

Normally OnForm2Click would get called fine if the user clicks on form2 when form1 is active, but with close-on-deactivate code above, OnForm2Click never gets called (this is a bit strange to me because double-click handlers are called just fine).

I cannot call `form1.Close()` from within `OnForm2Click()` as a solution because form2 has no reference to `form1`.

Thank you in advance for your solution.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `OnForm2Click` ?

Comment: In my test case `OnForm2Click` just prints to the debugger console (in reality I have multiple forms with click handlers and none of them get hit, I was just trying to describe the simple case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may solve your problem with a mouse hook. See:

[Hooks Overview (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx)